# Go-lang go tool works with Bash but not Fish

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables, fish

For those of you who have no idea what Fish is: http://fishshell.com/

Similarly, if you are not familiar with a Go coding environment and still wish to try and figure out this small puzzle, here is some info: http://golang.org/doc/code.html

Anyway, so I'm trying to set up a Go-lang dev. environment on a new machine where I'm giving Fish a try.

So I have `$GOPATH` set to `/home/<me>/workspace/go-workspace` in both `bash` and `fish`. This means that the `go` tool expects a `bin`, `pkg`, and `src` directory beneath that. Which is there.

However, typing `go get` while in a directory with some code (which would normally download it's dependencies) yields

```
package code.google.com/p/go.crypto/openpgp: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package code.google.com/p/go.crypto/openpgp/armor: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package code.google.com/p/go.crypto/ssh: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/codegangsta/cli: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package github.com/oleiade/reflections: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package launchpad.net/goamz/aws: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
package launchpad.net/goamz/s3: cannot download, $GOPATH not set. For more details see: go help gopath
```

I know this to be absolutely false because I can run `echo $GOPATH` and out pops the value I  have set.

Then, strangely, if I run the same command in `bash` with the same `$GOPATH` set, it just works.

Can anyone tell me why?

Or, more generally, can you tell me why a program would detect an environment variable in one shell but not another?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you remember to mark `$GOPATH` in fish as exported?

```
set -x GOPATH /home/<me>/workspace/go-workspace
```

It's not sufficient to test with

```
echo $GOPATH
```

since that will work regardless of whether the variable is exported. Check with

```
bash -c 'echo $GOPATH'
```

which will only print the value of `GOPATH` if it has been exported. In bash, you export variables like this:

```
export GOPATH=/home/<me>/workspace/go-workspace
```

Comment: I do believe the `-x` was what I was missing. D'oh.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks, but I had to use the `-g` modifier, as in `set -gx GOPATH <whatever>`

Answer (score 1):

Not all shell variables are environment variables. In `bash`, you'd have to `export` a variable for it to become an environment variable in child processes (if that variable wasn't already an environment variable). That is, assuming `FOO` is not defined already, then simply executing `FOO=bar` would not cause variable `FOO` to be visible in the environment of a child process. You'd have to follow that up with `export FOO`, or you could do it all at once by doing `export FOO=bar`.

I would assume something similar is going on in `fish`, where you must have `GOPATH` defined simply as a shell variable, and not as a shell variable also exported into the environment.